# ¿Cómo regreso al programa que llamó la ventana? Appcelerator en Mac

Tags: android, app, appcelerator

Llamo a una ventana de esta manera:

```
bot_flete.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var ModFlete = require('ModFlete');
    var fletePage = new ModFlete();
    fletePage.open();
});
```

Claro, allá arriba tengo la definición de la ventana actual y el botón de ese evento. La otra ventana que la tengo en el archivo ModFlete.js comienza así:

```
// INICIO DEL FORMULARIO DE IMPORTACION

function ModImport() {  
    var importsWin = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        title : "Pier17 App",
        backgroundColor : "#ffffff",
        layout: "vertical",
        exitOnClose : true
    });

    importsWin.backgroundImage = "realImport.jpg";

// ACTION BAR

importsWin.addEventListener("open", function(e) {
    if (Ti.Platform.osname === "android") {
        actionBar = importsWin.activity.actionBar;
        if (actionBar){
            actionBar.setTitle("Título");
            actionBar.setIcon("/images/back.png");      
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUp(false);

            activity = importsWin.activity;
            activity.onCreateOptionsMenu = function(e) {
                menu = e.menu;
                menuItem = menu.add({title:"Apagar", showAsAction:              
                Ti.Android.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM });
                menuItem.setIcon("/images/power.png");
                menuItem.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                    winmain.close();
                });
            };

        }
    }   
});
```

El caso es que en ese botoncito o imagen `back.png` quiero que cuando hagan click se regrese a la ventana que lo llamó y no lo he podido conseguir.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando abres una nueva ventana, se abre encina de la actual. Entonces, en teoría cuando cierras la nueva ventana se debe mostrar la ventana anterior.
Intenta cerrar la ventana actual cuando haces clic en la imagen.